# Erlang. Реализация нехвостовой рекурсии

Tags: рекурсия, erlang

Также, как и [эта тема](URL), мой вопрос носит чисто академический характер. Как в компиляторе Erlang'а реализована раскрутка нехвостовых рекурсий, какие там оптимизации применяются?  Буду рад также ссылкам на описание реализации данных рекурсий в других ЯП.

Comment: Единственная, вроде бы, оптимизация для нехвостовых рекурсий — подрезают стек, когда после вызова идет cons (опкод `put_list`). Истории коммитов старше R13 не нашел (а trim появилось в R12). Тут пример того, что делает компилятор:

- http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-November/062667.html
- http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-November/062673.html

Как/когда именно оно делается оптимизация - не вникал, кишки компилятора эрланга не для слабонервных.

Comment: Интересно. Спасибо за комментарий. Покопаю в этом направлении.